# get com port on which usb modem is connected in java

Tags: java, serial-port, usb, modem, javax.comm

how to get the com ports on which usb edge modem is connected in java program. neeed quick help.
kindly tell me which library to use to get com.. except javax.comm. I tried it but failed.
I didnt find way to install it properly its showing me error conitneously. :(

```
package commtest;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Formatter;
import org.smslib.helper.CommPortIdentifier;
import org.smslib.helper.SerialPort;

public class CommTest
{
    private static final String _NO_DEVICE_FOUND = "  no device found";

    private final static Formatter _formatter = new Formatter(System.out);

    static CommPortIdentifier portId;

    static Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> portList;

    static int bauds[] = { 9600, 14400, 19200, 28800, 33600, 38400, 56000, 57600, 115200 };

    /**
     * Wrapper around {@link CommPortIdentifier#getPortIdentifiers()} to be
     * avoid unchecked warnings.
     */
    private static Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> getCleanPortIdentifiers()
    {
        return CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("\nSearching for devices...");
        portList = getCleanPortIdentifiers();
        while (portList.hasMoreElements())
        {
            portId = portList.nextElement();
            if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
            {
                _formatter.format("%nFound port: %-5s%n", portId.getName());
                for (int i = 0; i < bauds.length; i++)
                {
                    SerialPort serialPort = null;
                    _formatter.format("       Trying at %6d...", bauds[i]);
                    try
                    {
                        InputStream inStream;
                        OutputStream outStream;
                        int c;
                        String response;
                        serialPort = portId.open("SMSLibCommTester", 1971);
                        serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN);
                        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(bauds[i], SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                        inStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
                        outStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                        serialPort.enableReceiveTimeout(1000);
                        c = inStream.read();
                        while (c != -1)
                            c = inStream.read();
                        outStream.write('A');
                        outStream.write('T');
                        outStream.write('\r');
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        response = "";
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        c = inStream.read();
                        while (c != -1)
                        {
                            sb.append((char) c);
                            c = inStream.read();
                        }
                        response = sb.toString();
                        if (response.indexOf("OK") >= 0)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                System.out.print("  Getting Info...");
                                outStream.write('A');
                                outStream.write('T');
                                outStream.write('+');
                                outStream.write('C');
                                outStream.write('G');
                                outStream.write('M');
                                outStream.write('M');
                                outStream.write('\r');
                                response = "";
                                c = inStream.read();
                                while (c != -1)
                                {
                                    response += (char) c;
                                    c = inStream.read();
                                }
                                System.out.println(" Found: " + response.replaceAll("\\s+OK\\s+", "").replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", ""));
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                System.out.println(_NO_DEVICE_FOUND);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println(_NO_DEVICE_FOUND);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.print(_NO_DEVICE_FOUND);
                        Throwable cause = e;
                        while (cause.getCause() != null)
                        {
                            cause = cause.getCause();
                        }
                        System.out.println(" (" + cause.getMessage() + ")");
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (serialPort != null)
                        {
                            serialPort.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nTest complete.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not related with USB, AT Commands and so on... if you would've read carefully the error message, you would've had the answer:

```
win32com.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit.
```

The topic was alredy address here: [Javax.comm API on 64-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959743/problem-of-using-the-javax-comm-api-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

This method is working for me.This code will automatically detect port with which GSM modem connected and send SMS.

```
public class ModamSMS {


public void sendMessage(String num, String massage) throws Exception {

    SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("", "COM5", 9600, "", "");
    gateway.setInbound(true);
    gateway.setOutbound(true);
    OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
    InboundNotification inboundNotification = new InboundNotification();
    Service service = Service.getInstance();
    service.setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
    service.setInboundMessageNotification(inboundNotification);
    service.addGateway(gateway);
    service.startService();

    OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage(num, massage);
    service.sendMessage(msg);
}

public ArrayList sendBulkMessage(ArrayList<String> numbers, String massage)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException, SMSLibException {

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    String connectedport = getConnectedport(numbers.get(0), massage);
    System.out.println(connectedport + " port in bulsksmssend method");
    if (connectedport != null) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("", connectedport, 9600, "", "");

        try {

            // gateway.setInbound(true);
            gateway.setOutbound(true);

            OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();

            // InboundNotification inboundNotification = new
            // InboundNotification();
            Service service = Service.getInstance();
            service.setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
            // service.setInboundMessageNotification(inboundNotification);
            service.addGateway(gateway);
            service.startService();

            for (int i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++) {

                String num = (String) numbers.get(i);
                OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage(num, i + " " + massage);
                System.out.println(i + " " + massage);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                service.sendMessage(msg);
                list.add(num + " Sms send succes");

            }
            Service.getInstance().stopService();

        } catch (SMSLibException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));

            writfile(sw.toString());
        }

        Service.getInstance().removeGateway(gateway);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make ! \n Modam is correctly inseted\nYou hava SMS package\n ");
    }
    return list;
}

public class InboundNotification implements IInboundMessageNotification {
    // @Override
    // Get triggered when a SMS is received
    public void process(AGateway gateway, Message.MessageTypes messageTypes, InboundMessage inboundMessage) {
        System.out.println(inboundMessage);
        try {
            gateway.deleteMessage(inboundMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class OutboundNotification implements IOutboundMessageNotification {

    // Get triggered when a SMS is sent
    public void process(AGateway gateway, OutboundMessage outboundMessage) {
        System.out.println(outboundMessage);
    }
}

public String getConnectedport(String num, String msge)
        throws TimeoutException, GatewayException, SMSLibException, IOException, InterruptedException {

    ArrayList<String> allports = new ArrayList<>();

    Enumeration ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier port = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();
        String type;
        switch (port.getPortType()) {
        case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
            type = "Parallel";
            break;
        case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
            allports.add(port.getName());
            type = "Serial";
            break;
        default: /// Shouldn't happen
            type = "Unknown";
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(port.getName() + ": " + type);
        allports.add(port.getName());
    }
    String connectedport = null;
    for (int a = 0; a < allports.size(); a++) {
        connectedport = getport(allports.get(a), num, msge);
        if (connectedport != null) {
            a = allports.size();
            System.out.println(connectedport + " port in for loop");

        }

    }

    return connectedport;

}

private String getport(String port, String num, String msge)
        throws TimeoutException, GatewayException, SMSLibException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    String returnport = null;

    SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("", port, 9600, "", "");
    gateway.setInbound(true);
    gateway.setOutbound(true);
    OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
    InboundNotification inboundNotification = new InboundNotification();
    Service service = Service.getInstance();
    service.setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
    service.setInboundMessageNotification(inboundNotification);
    try {
        service.addGateway(gateway);
        service.startService();

        OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage(num, msge);
        service.sendMessage(msg);
        returnport = port;
        System.out.println(returnport + " port in port finding method");

    } catch (GatewayException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SMSLibException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Service.getInstance().stopService();
    Service.getInstance().removeGateway(gateway);
    return returnport;

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    BasicConfigurator.configure();

    ModamSMS app = new ModamSMS();
    ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add("+923075142199");
    numbers.add("+923075142199");

    try {
        // app.sendMessage("+923075142199","plz Allah it shoud work");
        app.sendBulkMessage(numbers,
                "hy this is me Abdulrehman javed .Who are you and how are you.This is testing sms so do not worry");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.printStackTrace();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));

        writfile(sw.toString());
    }
}

public static void writfile(String content) {

    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;

    try {

        fw = new FileWriter("Error.txt");
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        try {

            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();

            if (fw != null)
                fw.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
}
```