# Unable to parse actuall data from com port

Tags: java, java-communication-api

I have a `3G Modem` which is installed on my computer on `COM9` port. I want to read incoming `sms` from that port. i am using below code.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;
import javax.comm.SerialPort;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEvent;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEventListener;

/**
 *
 * @author IamUsman
 */
public class ReadingPorts implements SerialPortEventListener, Runnable {

    static CommPortIdentifier portId;
    static Enumeration portList;
    static SerialPort port;
    static InputStream inputStream;
    static Thread readThread;
    static byte buffer[];

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
            portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
            if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
                if (portId.getName().equals("COM9")) {
                    if (!portId.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
                        ReadingPorts rp = new ReadingPorts();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("This port is already used by some other program");
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ReadingPorts() {
        try {
            port = (SerialPort) portId.open("Custom", 500);
            inputStream = port.getInputStream();
            System.out.println("** Connected To Streams **");
            port.addEventListener(this);
            port.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
            port.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            port.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);
            port.enableReceiveTimeout(500);
            System.out.println("................................");
            readThread = new Thread(this);
            readThread.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        System.out.println("In Callback method");
        switch(event.getEventType()){
            case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
                buffer = new byte[8];
                try{
                    while (inputStream.available()>0) {
                        int numBytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    }
                    System.out.println(new String(buffer));
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();;
        }

    }
}
```

I am reading the data but it is meaningful. Things that i read are below

`+CMTI: "SM",14`

Comment: You need to explain what problem you encounter. An error? Unwanted behavior? What behavior is expected instead?

Comment: What API version of Communications API you are using and on what OS? Windows x64? Then you probably ran into trouble. This explains why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959743/javax-comm-api-on-64-bit-windows Look here for a cool alternative to JC-Api: https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/

Comment: Sorry. review the question i just edit. I am able to read the data from 3G modem but the text that i read is meaninless. how can i get the actuall sms message

Answer (score 0):

> the text that I read is meaningless

That's because you read it with the following meaningless code:

```
while (inputStream.available()>0) {
    int numBytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
}
System.out.println(new String(buffer));
```

It should be:

```
while (inputStream.available()>0) {
    int numBytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
    System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, numBytes));
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and i am getting this:   ^BOOT:
27789999
,0,0,0,3
9


^MODE:
3,0


^SRVST
:0


^MODE:
0,0


^RSSI:
99


^MODE:
0,0


^RSSI:
18


^SRVST
:1


^MODE:
3,3


^SRVST
:2

Comment: Is this am i supposed to get ? please help me