# Java Comm API Issue with dll

Tags: java

I am trying to install the comm API but i get this error :

```
Error loading win32com: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\win32com.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

I placed the comm.jar file in the jre/lib/ext directory, javax.comm.properties file in the jre/lib directory and the win32com.dll in the jre/bin directory. Any ideas how can i resolve this ?

Comment: I know that . The question is what i can do ?

Comment: Also, those files should've been copied to jre folder or jdk ?

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message!

> ...win32com.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

I don't know what are you doing and how it should be done but I see the problem in this file `win32com.dll` 32 tells me that it suits 32 bit OS. Download another 64 bit version of this file and try again. Good luck!

Comment: i know that too but i didnt found a 64 bit version

Answer (score 0):

Try to download 32bit version of your JRE or java. then put it there. 
(Java already stopped support javax.comm library) So they do not have x64 bit dll to work with 64 bit java

look at this

[Javax.comm API on 64-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959743/javax-comm-api-on-64-bit-windows)