# windows 7 64 bits didn't found win32comm

Tags: java, java-io

i wanted to list the serial port available on my pc so i used javax.comm library,and i got a problem with win32com.dll it doesn't work on my windows 7 64 bits is that version is for windo 32 bits or also for 64 bit too ? because i didn't find a link of win32com.dll for windows 7 64 bit , please can you help me to find that link ? and that's why i get when i run my program .
and thank you.

[image]

Comment: Use the 32-bit version of Java.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [This SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959743/javax-comm-api-on-64-bit-windows).